# 5 radio buttons and 2 spinners

Tags: spinner

I am creating my first ever android app which is a English-Metric Unit Converter. It contains 5 radio buttons and 2 Spinners. radio buttons are the measurement types(Area, Length, Weight, Volume and temperature) while spinners provides choices whether into what measurement system the user wants to convert it with.Both spinners has the same Value namely : "English" and "Metric". the first spinner is labeled as "Convert from:" while the second is "Convert to:". to convert, user must first identify :

1.Measurement type,

2.From what measurement system and

3.Into what measurement system he wants.
 When "NEXT" button it clicked, the conversion layout will open but will depend on this 3.
I wanted it to be:
if spinner1 is set to "English", spinner 2 must be automatically set to "Metric". in additional, spinners must not have the same value. Can anyone help me with this? i needed it badly.
Thanks.